# Line of sight shader

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics

Strategy games (such as [Door Kickers](https://youtu.be/3LHNV8s8ok8)) use a player's unit's line-of-sight as a major game feature. To provide feedback to the player regarding which areas are in view and which are not, different colours are used to display areas that are currently visible by a unit and areas which are not.
Can anyone recommend an approach for creating this effect in a shader?

Comment: They're just changing the colour somehow based on line-of-sight. The hard part is *calculating* line-of-sight.

Comment: @user253751 Yes....

Comment: There are lots of [tutorials online](https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/) and [past Q&A here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/120430/39518) about implementing this "visibility polygon" effect. How have you tried to implement it based on the research you've done so far? Have you run into a specific obstacle applying these existing answers that we can help you with?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, it looks like the term 'visibility polygon' is the appropriate lingo. Those links should get me started.